# Too many materials! (Help with imported model)

Tags: texturing, materials, baking

I am very new to modelling, and have no clue what I'm doing; I'm trying to import a model into a game, but the model I'm using has too many materials, with 43 each dedicated to a texture (the game has a limit of 10). I've baked the textures into 3 files, but I have no clue what to do with them. I don't know how to delete existing materials, or add any of my own, and would love any help I could get on this seemingly simple problem.

Comment: If you've baked the Diffuse for example you just need to plug the Image Texture node into the Base Color input of the Principled BSDF node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Removing materials

With your object selected, go to the Properties Editor, Materials tab.

Here you can see the material slots of your model, with each slot containing a material.
What you can do to remove all of them is to spam clicking the <kbd>-</kbd> button next to the material slots list until you have nothing left in the list:

[image: remove material slots button]

### Making a new material

Once the list is empty, you can click the <kbd>New</kbd> button, which will create a new material and assign it to a new slot:

[image: New material button]

By default, Blender will setup your material with a [Principled BSDF — (see Blender Manual)](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html). This shader is ideal, among other things, for exporting into modern game engines.

### Edit the material

In the Shader editor, add your textures using <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> → Texture → Image Texture, or by simply doing a drag-and-drop of your files into the Shader Editor.
Now, what to do with your textures entirely depends on the type of texture. Let's say you have a color texture, you can plug it into the "Base Color" input:

[image: basic Principled setup]

If you need more specific setups, you can look at the Principled BSDF manual, or tell us here what kind of textures you have.

Comment: Thank you! Worked a charm!

Comment: with pleasure! Don't forget to mark my post as the correct answer